# Source: call to eval() or related function blocked by CSP

Tags: apache2, content-security-policy

I am receiving the following error:

> *Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). Source: call to eval() or related
>   function blocked by CSP.*

The site is running Laravel, but I have introduced a simple `index.html` to rule out that possibility:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Which gives thew same error.

Here is the relevant code from `httpd.conf`

> httpd-2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1.x86_64

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <Directory />
    Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always set x-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' *.pusher.com; img-src 'self'; style-src *.fontawesome.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src *.fontawesome.com https://fonts.gstatic.com;"
    Header always set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin"
  </Directory>
```

I have also attempted using my domain `default-src *.domain.com;` with the same result

**EDIT:** Is this what you mean?
This is a 'view source' of the `index.html as the server sees it, with the error as shown when viewing that page via the browser. Also since the site is locked to only a handful of IP addresses, i would find it very odd if something is being injected

[image]

Comment: It seems like you need to look at the actual HTML document that’s being sent over the wire — not the source you’re maintaining on the server side. And/or disable all your extensions. Because the only way a browser would emit the error message cited in the question is either if there’s something in your server-side system that causes some JavaScript to be injected into the HTML document the browser ends up receiving from your server, or if you have some extension installed that’s injecting JavaScript into the document. Or else you’re actually experiencing some kind of MITM attack.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I have made an edit to the OP. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. I see the screenshot shown is from Firefox devtools. Are you able to reproduce the error in Chrome or Safari? And if not, have you tried disabling your extensions in Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved - Thank you **sideshowbarker**

It was a plugin, `Vue.js devtools` to be specific

I hadn't even thought a plugin could do that.

I am curious now though as to how to notify a user if a plugin causes that issue in the future